# How do I retrieve a comma-delimited string of values from a text box?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox AND 3 checkboxes; checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3

In textbox we have 1,2,3

If I type in textbox1 = 1,2 then

checkbox1 and checkbox2 will be checked and checkbox3 will remain unchecked.....

How to do this in vb.net

Comment: Fixed the casing. To our new user friend: we go nuts when people type in all caps around here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28VS.80%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Sorry, I was just answering the question in your title. I was too busy trying to clean up your question to provide a proper answer, so I pointed you in the right direction instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work out for you:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each s As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(","c)
        Dim i As Integer
        If Int32.TryParse(s, i) Then
            Dim result As Control = Page.FindControl("checkBox" + i.ToString())
            If result IsNot Nothing Then
                DirectCast(result, CheckBox).Checked = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If your checkboxes are within a different container instead of the main Page you'll need to call FindControl`on that control instead of`Page.FindControl`.

EDIT: it sounds like you're going from checkbox selections to build up the textbox value. Based on your comment it also looks like you have a trailing comma, perhaps because you're appending a comma in a loop. You should provide us with code to better understand what you're doing.

To answer the question in your comment, to sort "3,1," you could use this:

```
Dim input As String = "3,1,"
Dim split As String() = input.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim result As String = String.Join(",", split.OrderBy(Function(i) i).ToArray())
```

In reality you might want to order by an Integer type, not by strings, since the sorting order will eventually surprise you for larger numbers.

Comment: can i direct do it when i check 1st check box then 2nd checkbox then it will direct show in textbox 1,2 with out button click...........

Comment: @user495854 your question isn't clear. Your main question said you wanted to type "1,2" in the textbox, then check the appropriate checkboxes. Now you're saying you want the textbox to be updated based on which checkboxes are checked? Please let me know what you want to do exactly. And yes, you could get rid of the button click, but there'll be postbacks on each event handler, so perhaps you'll want to use an UpdatePanel.

Comment: @user495854 see my edit. Also your question has been closed. I suggest asking a new question and asking a clear question, providing us with code to see what you're attempting to do, and NO CAPS when you ask your question.

Comment: +1 for the effort. I didn't feel like writing his program for him.

Comment: @Robert thanks, I know the feeling... it took a different turn than expected.

Comment: Simply i want .............

when i check checkbox1 first and then checkbox3 then i will show in textbox as 3,1, 

but i want 1,3 only in textbox either the user choose....checkbox1 and checkbox2 it will shows in textbox as 1,2

how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head

```
dim v = Split(textbox.text, ",")
for each i in v
    select case val(i)
       case 1:checkbox1.checked =true
       case 2:checkbox2.checked = true
       case.....
    end select
next
```

Comment: This will only select first checkbox1 if i write 1,3 in textbox ...

Comment: Is there any way to do this without Case ?