# checkbox selected values in comma sepearted string in textbox using vb.net !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 checkboxes and 1 textbox

checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3

when i check first checkbox1 and then checkbox3 then in textbox it will appear as 1,3 exactly........ !!

using vb.net only.........

Comment: I don't have the appropriate reputation to officially mark this, but this is pretty close to a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090421/how-do-i-retrieve-a-comma-delimited-string-of-values-from-a-text-box-closed

Comment: ^^ Which was asked by the same user, just an hour earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sb.Append(CStr(IIf(CheckBox1.Checked, "1 ", "")))
    sb.Append(CStr(IIf(CheckBox2.Checked, "2 ", "")))
    sb.Append(CStr(IIf(CheckBox3.Checked, "3 ", "")))
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString.Trim
End Sub
```

Comment: i wanna use it with 45 check boxes

right now ....i wanna try .....with 3 checkboxes and 1 textbox.......

if i check checkbox1 and checkbox2 or checkbox3 and checkbox1 it will instantly shown in textbox1 as 1,2 or 1,3

Comment: @user495854 is your problem that my answer is ugly with a large number of checkboxes (fair enough) or that it doesn't work even with just 3 checkboxes (if so, how doesn't it work)?

Comment: I do not think this is worth a full answer but here is a fix to hawbsl's so that you do not get the trailing comma: Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim text As String
        sb.Append(CStr(IIf(CheckBox1.Checked, "1, ", "")))
        sb.Append(CStr(IIf(CheckBox2.Checked, "2, ", "")))
        sb.Append(CStr(IIf(CheckBox3.Checked, "3, ", "")))
        text = sb.ToString
        If text.EndsWith(", ") = True Then
            TextBox1.Text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 2)
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = text.Trim
        End If

Comment: I think he wanted it to be just like yours, but with commas separating the numbers and with no trailing comma. I sort of think, maybe, based on his duplicate question that is what he wanted. Your answer is correct based on what he put in THIS question so I gave you +1 =)