# How to add comma seperated values according to the checkboxes in textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 checkboxes and 1 textbox

i use only these controls mentioned above ..

I want ---- when i check checkbox1 and checkbox2 then it will display in textbox1 as 1,2 as it is as the same ascending order not 1,2, or 2,1,

I use this type of coding in asp.net (VB) , i wanna use this coding for 45 checkboxes........

Can anybody solve this problem in asp.net (vb)

Comment: Can you make your question a little more clear? Your second paragraph is really very confusing I feel!!

Comment: I ahve edited my question, have a look !!

Comment: Do you want the numbers to A. always appear in numerical sequence by the number.  B. appear in the sequence checked.  C. something else. ??

Comment: Means if i checked checkbox1 and checkbox2 then in textbox1 it will appear as 1,2 only

Comment: Actually that does not really answer Mark's question.

Comment: Same question asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091208/checkbox-selected-values-in-comma-sepearted-string-in-textbox-using-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

JS solution (needs adaptation to your markup) as question is tagged with `javascript`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O. 4121588</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gMax = 45; 

        function $(aId) {
            return document.getElementById(aId);
        }

        // generates gMax checkboxes with value from 1 to gMax 
        function onload() {
            var form = $('theForm');

            for (var i = 1; i != gMax; i++) {
                var cb = document.createElement('input');
                cb.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
                cb.setAttribute('id', 'checkbox-' + i);
                cb.setAttribute('value', i);
                form.appendChild(cb);
            }
        }

        // update the result textarea
        function updateResult() {
            var num = [ ];

            for (var i = 1; i != gMax; i++) {
                var cb = $('checkbox-' + i);

                if (cb.checked) {
                    num.push(cb.getAttribute('value'));
                }
            }

            $('result').innerHTML = num.join(", ");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='onload()'>
    <form id="theForm"></form>
    <input type="button" id="resultBtn" value="Result"
        onclick="updateResult()" />
    <br/>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested under Chrome 9.0.570.1 dev

Comment: how to use this with vb.net ?

Comment: As it seems, you are using Prototype. Why then not create the input like `new Element("input", {"type": "checkbox", "id": "checkbox-" + i, "value": i});`.

Comment: @philgiese, I don't. @user, don't you have html in your project?

Comment: Hey but i already have 3 checkboxes and 1 textbox in webform

i just want that .....

when i anybody check 1 and 2 checkbox it will display in textbox as 1,2

thats the simple procedure i needed ....

Comment: @user, I don't have any checkboxes nor your webform so I need to generate them. Adapt `gMax` to your number of checkboxes ; change the id of your check-boxes to be `checkbox-N` where `N` is 1,2,3 ; change the id of your textbox to `result` and remove `onLoad` and there you go. Alternatively you can post your markup. As a side note, you should know that this is a "helping" site, not a "do my work" site..