# Insert checkbox checked value when checked to textbox as comma seperated string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Insert checkbox checked value when checked to textbox as comma seperated string in vb.net or javascript

suppose i have 3 checkboxes and and 1 textboxes in my webpage.aspx

when i checked checkbox1 and checkbox2 then in textbox it will appear as 1,2 only on checkboxes checked event ...

and i want its revert also :

if i set textbox de

Comment: Please proof your question for tyops, and make sure to provide some example code. We in the matrix see code better than words.

Comment: @user Please let us know whether you are using c# user controls or javascript controls , so that we can help

Comment: -1 since hawbsl already answered this the 3rd time you asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091208/checkbox-selected-values-in-comma-sepearted-string-in-textbox-using-vb-net. Which part of his answer did not work for you? Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

It should pretty straight forward

Checkbox should have the following event

OnCheckedChanged see here for more reference
      http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_checkbox.asp.

In that event update the textbox count , like that bind the events and whenever event is changed please update the text box.

```
 textbox.Text=""; // textbox should be the id of textbox control
```

it should be pretty straigforwad

as you didn't provide too many details , i am providing you an approach