# putting text in a textbox when 2 checkboxes are checked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 webforms controls: 3 checkboxes and 1 textbox.

When I check checkbox1 and checkbox2, then in the textbox it should appear as `1,2`.

How can this be done using ASP.NET webforms controls?

Comment: Duplicate questions by the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091208/checkbox-selected-values-in-comma-sepearted-string-in-textbox-using-vb-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130800/insert-checkbox-checked-value-when-checked-to-textbox-as-comma-seperated-string, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127492/vb-net-add-checkbox-checked-values-to-textbox-closed -- in addition to many, many others.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use JavaScript to modify the contents of the textbox.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var c1 = document.getElementById('<%=myCheckBox1.ClientID%>');
    var c2 = document.getElementById('<%=myCheckBox2.ClientID%>');
    var c3 = document.getElementById('<%=myCheckBox3.ClientID%>');
    var t = document.getElementById('<%=myTextBox.ClientID%>');

    function setTextBox()
    {
        if(c1.checked) t.value = "1";
        if(c2.checked) t.length > 0 ? ",2" : "2";
        if(c3.checked) t.length > 0 ? ",3" : "3";
    }
</script>
```

Then for your checkboxes add the following snippet:

```
onClientClick="setTextBox()"
```

EDIT: If you choose to use jquery, some of this code can probably be reduced/simplified. If you need to make the logic for what gets displayed a little more complicated (such as changing the textbox value when 1 and 2 are clicked but 3 is not, etc) this can all be accomplished with JavaScript in `setTextBox()`.

Comment: okey tell me....jquery ... code...but i wanna use asp.net standard controls (checkbox & textbox) not html

Comment: @user495854 - this script uses asp.net standard controls. It just doesn't require a postback to perform the change. The answers put forth in your other identical question more than answer the straight forward postback method.